# MinGW leftover headers prevent GCC from compiling simple project properly

Tags: gcc

Today I've tried to install MinGW in order to compile my simple TicTacToe game for Windows system (I'm on Ubuntu 16.04). Howevr, after few attempts I just let it go. Unfortunately, I can't compile simple "Hello World!" program now due to the fact that MinGW overwrote my headers in /usr/local/includes. I am pretty sure that's the case as my stdio.h start with:

```
This file is part of the mingw-w64 runtime package.
```

I've tried to `purge mingw-64`, reinstall `build-essential` and `gcc`, to no result. I would rather not go for a system reinstall as I have rather big movie collection in there. Can anybody help me? (Here's the list of warnings that prevent me from compiling pliss.c - which is literally a printf and return). I can share my stdio.h with you, however I am pretty certain that's just a leftover from MinGW.
Thanks in advance and have a good one.

Comment: There are no files from standard packages in `/usr/local/*`. All of those are installed from third party. You can delete everything in `/usr/local/*` and your distro packages shouldn't care.

Comment: I owe you a beer. Or bear, whichever you prefer. Thank you kindly. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are no files from standard packages in `/usr/local/*`. All of those are installed from third party. You can delete everything in `/usr/local/*` and your distro packages shouldn't care.
                    – n.m.